# Capturing inter-service communication in microservices

Tags: http, microservices, packet-capture

Does anybody have experience with *capturing* **inter-service http communication** packets in a microservices setup? I'm just exploring options and would be interested in any approach.

Comment: If the provided answer works for you - great! Otherwise, you'll want to provide more details and flesh out your question more with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I typically use [Fiddler](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/wireshark#fiddler) or `tcpdump` to debug. You can use Fiddler as a man in the middle to monitor data, or tcpdump to capture traffic on a port.